# angular $modal domcontentloaded event

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a angular app and use angular-bootstrap to create modal popup, In my case i need bind some event listener on the element, however as the template is loaded asynchronous i can't process this operation immediately in the controller function so i set a timer to do this job. I want to know if there exists any event like DOMContentLoaded emitted when the template is loaded so I can listen in the controller.

```html
var pop = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/template/defineDashboard.html',
    backdrop: 'static',
    controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$notify', '$timeout', '$personalDashboard', '$maintainMetric', 'dashboard', defineDashboardCtrl],
    resolve: {
     dashboard: function(){
      return item;
     }
    }
   });



$timeout(function(){
      $('input#input-business').bind('click', function(event){
                event && event.stopPropagation();
                $('div#business-list').show();
               });

               $(window).bind('click', function(event){
                if(event.target !== $('input#input-keyword')[0]){
                 $('div#business-list').hide();
                }
               });
     }, 500);
```

Comment: What the directive `$modal` you are using?

Comment: angular-bootstrap and i read the source code find nothing useful, i'm not sure if i missed something important.

Comment: I think `$modal.open` function can return `promise`, that resolved when template loading. Update your question by adding url for `$modal` library.